# What is an overview page of a newspaper (online) called

Tags: technology

I am actually working at a German newspaper as a programmer, so this question might sound embarrassing or silly to you. Still we have a dispute on how to name the "overview" pages on our website.

With "overview" page I mean this: We have article pages, the webpages that show an article, and we have pages that list many articles, like our home page or the start pages of certain sections of or newspaper (sports, politics) etc.. I am wondering what you would call the latter.

article -> article page
"overview" -> ???

Comment: "News summary"? "Feature index"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. To ask for a label for something, you ask *what* it is called, not *how*. That aside, your question might be strengthened with a screenshot or links to examples. I would also point out that the general public may use a term that is different from what an editor would use (e.g. *section front*), or from an advertising buyer (e.g. *channel home*), or from a CMS developer (e.g. *portal screen*).

Comment: Hinweis: aktuell = _currently, now_, nicht _actually_.

Comment: @KarlG I am trying to say "tatsächlich" expressing how ridiculous my question is.

Comment: @choster thanks I am going to give it more thought

Comment: Effectively its a contents page.

Comment: You could think on the lines of "Section," "Section Title," "Section Start" or similar which is both publishing- and programming- compatible terminology.

Comment: "What is it called", not "How…".

Answer (score 1):

As a non-specialist, I normally expect the “home page” to do the job that you describe. I know of no other term in general use.

Regarding the comment made on your use of “actually”, it may be used as you have used it if you wish to emphasise that you are a programmer, despite your reader’s assumption that - working for a newspaper - you might be a journalist.

Comment: There's only one home page, in my usage, so this term does not work for other index/landing/contents/whatever pages for the various sections. For example, I would call latimes.com the homepage, but not latimes.com/sports or latimes.com/entertainment-arts.